# Loading takes a while when i set UIImage to a NSData with a url.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

```
NSData *imageUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"] ]];
cell.thumbnailImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageUrl];
```

this is how i use `imageUrl` to load them into `UIImage` but it takes a while to load and the program seems like it crashed or entered to an infinite loop.

How can i make the content of `UIImage` with url but faster?

Comment: This is synchronous call. You need to make asynchronous call

Comment: how can i do that? @San

Comment: use sdwebimage it takes u very faster

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sdwebimage` and down load the library file from [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

the few steps you do follow

add the `sdwebimage` in your project after that

in your .h file

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

in your .m file

call the single line in your `cellforRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: try this any queries I am waiting

Comment: just import the folder in your project

Comment: would you mind modify this ?

 myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:myImageString];

this is what i used to show in detailedVIewConroller how can i set it with this new url content?

myImageString was segued with

destViewController.myImage =[[self.filteredContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageString"];


i changed imageString to imageUrl but don't know how to handle in receiver part

Comment: u want to show the particular image in next view controller

Comment: simple friend, use singleton or NSUserdefault for the move of one view controller to another view controller, just wait I post another one answer for your queries

Comment: why would i use NSUserdefaut i don't get it? I m already able to fetch all other items with segue.And i got the imageUrl. How can i set it to a UIImage with this new lib

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use AsyncImageView a beautiful implementation by Nicklockwood -father of iCarousel.

[Link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)
it is very simple to use.

```
    #import "AsyncImageView.h"
```

and in all imageViews do this.

```
    [imageView setImage:@"default.png"];
    [imageView setImageURL:@"whateverurl/whateverimage.png"];
```

In your case it would be:

```
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageURL:@"yourURL"];
```

It works like a charm, and my code is in production. But if you still want your code to work try this:

```
 UIActivityIndicator *activity =[[UIActivityIndicator alloc] initWithStyle:UIActivityIndicatorWhite];
 [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:activity];

 cell.thumbnailImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default~cell~image.png"];      

 dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
 dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)
 { 
   [activity startAnimating];
   [self loadImages];
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
           NSData *imageUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"] ]];
           cell.thumbnailImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageUrl];          [activity stopAnimating];
           [activty setHidden:YES];
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because every time your cell goes off screen your image is released and if you scroll it back on screen you will have to download your image again. Simply cache your image when downloaded and check if exists use it if not download from internet. You can use third party library like SDWebImage [GitHub link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Import `SDWebImageView+WebCache.h` and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use the following

```
[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"] placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSOperationQueue so that you can perform the loading of the data on a background thread.
After that you should set the image on the main queue.

```
// Assume queue is created
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSData *imageUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"] ]];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageUrl];
    }];
}];
```

For more about NSOperationQueue see the [docs about NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

So try to load image asynchronous.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Answer (score 0):

Use gcd to populate the images,

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"] ]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
   UIImage *image = nil;
   image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl: imageUrl]];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
 });
})
```

You will probably want to store the image to some model object, also track if the download has been initiated, since you would not want to queue up the request for the same image url.