# Weird UIScrollview behaviour in IOS 7 in IPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiscrollview, avfoundation

I am working on a video-related application. For this, I used `AVFoundation` framework to capture image and video. I am capturing an image and showing that captured image in next view, where image view is a `subview` to the `scrollview`. It's working fine in iPhone 5,iPhone 5s and also in iPad but in iPhone 4 after capturing the image and while attaching to `scrollView`, the app is becoming slow. The scroll view is  not scrolling smoothly as in other devices. I am not getting issue where it has gone wrong. I am using the below code to capture images:

```
-(void)capturePhoto
{
    _ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
//  - input
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:NULL];
NSError *error = nil;
if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
{
    if ([device isFlashModeSupported:AVCaptureFlashModeOff])
    {
        device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOff;
    }

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
//  - output
_dataOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
_dataOutput.outputSettings = outputSettings;
//  - output
NSMutableDictionary *settings;
settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
             forKey:(__bridge id) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
_dataOutputVideo = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
_dataOutputVideo.videoSettings = settings;
[_dataOutputVideo setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[_session addInput:deviceInput];
[_session addOutput:_dataOutput];
[_session addOutput:_dataOutputVideo];
  // _session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
  _session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
   // _session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
[_session startRunning];
// add gesture
//  UIGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapGesture:)];
// gr.delegate = self;
// [self.touchView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
_focusView = [[UIView alloc] init];
CGRect imageFrame = _focusView.frame;
imageFrame.size.width = 80;
imageFrame.size.height = 80;
_focusView.frame = imageFrame;
_focusView.center = CGPointMake(160, 202);
CALayer *layer = _focusView.layer;
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.5, 2.5);
layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
layer.borderWidth = 2;
layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
[self.touchView addSubview:_focusView];
_focusView.alpha = 0;
_isShowFlash = NO;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.touchView];
UIView *footerView = [self.view viewWithTag:2];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:footerView];
}
```

Later I am attaching to scroll view like this:

```
scrollImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 340)];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:appdelegate.capturedImgData];
        UIImage *tempImage=[self resizeImage:image withWidth:320 withHeight:340];
        NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage,1.0);//0.25f
        NSLog(@"image  is %@",image);
        scrollImgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        // scrollImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        // UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [postScrollView addSubview:scrollImgView];
```

Please give me suggestions if any one faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing

`_session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` to

```
_session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium
```

Answer (score 0):

your coding is fine , and also is not a problem in in device, it may be occur

```
1. network problem

2. device memory is already loaded fully.

3. some Data conversation also taken times
```

here

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:appdelegate.capturedImgData];   
    UIImage *tempImage=[self resizeImage:image withWidth:320 withHeight:340];  //
    NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage,1.0);//0.25f


 the above code u having used

 1. data conversion is taken high and also taken the 2 time of image conversion   optimize any `NSData`

 2. third line is improve the `quality` of your image-- this also take the time for image conversion.
```

in my suggestion

```
1. use `Asychronous method`

  -- sdwebimage  
  -- Asychronous Imageview
  -- NSOperation_Queue
  -- Dispatch im main_queue
```

use anyone of this , it will be  taken the some response for you. in my suggestion is use `SDWebImage`.. use this link [Loading takes a while when i set UIImage to a NSData with a url.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607888/loading-takes-a-while-when-i-set-uiimage-to-a-nsdata-with-a-url/23608109#23608109)