# UICollectionView Jerks When Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, asynchronous, scroll, uicollectionview

In my project I am dealing with a collection view contains 9 images(30 KB each) per page. 
When I load images into the collectionView directly from my project resources and scroll,it scrolls smoothly. But If I download those (exactly same size) images from server asynchronously and scroll(after download), it jerks. I think as I am downloading asynchronously and cache it after downloaded, it should be as smooth as fetching and scroll from resources.Also it is smoother if I deal with images not more than 15 KB per images.

I am using https://github.com/erwinmaza/EMAsyncImageView downloader.

Any help will be appreciated!!!!

Comment: Try with AFNetworking.

Comment: use this link for smooth scrolling ur cells , it helps for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607888/loading-takes-a-while-when-i-set-uiimage-to-a-nsdata-with-a-url/23608109#23608109