# UIImage not displaying the image from the service url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I used the following code to display the image from the service url. But it shows nothing. Can anyone help me to do that.

```
cell.title.text = title;
                    cell.description.text = description;
                    cell.receivedDate.text = receivedDate;
                    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailImg[indexPath.row]];
                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                            cell.vendorImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        });
                    });
```

When i had a breakpoint in cell.vendorImage.image its shows the url what i have passed but it does not show any image in UIImage.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Refer http://dbrajkovic.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/load-images-asynchronously-in-a-uitableview-using-gcd-grand-central-dispatch/

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607888/loading-takes-a-while-when-i-set-uiimage-to-a-nsdata-with-a-url/23608109#23608109

Comment: Good to know your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imageUrl"] ]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
   UIImage *image = nil;
   image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl: imageUrl]];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
 });
})
```

Comment: Check the NSData is nil or what.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the image data in a Async way,so you need to inform the TableView when downloading is done.

So ,try this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                        cell.vendorImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });
```